# how to write "select * from PUB_PAGE_MENUSTRUCTUR where PARENTID is null" using lambda

Tags: sql, lambda

This is my lambda to get the data from pub_page_menustructur

[image: DataHelper.DataObj.QueryTable<PUB_PAGE_MENUSTRUCTUR>(SystemType.H0, p => p.PARENTID != null);]

**DataHelper.DataObj.QueryTable(SystemType.H0, p=>p.PARENTID == null)** this is the lambda expression i had write. it have the same effection as "select * from pub_page_menustructur where parentid = null" show in the picture. is there any other way to show as "parentid is null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way work for you if you are using Entity Framework

```
var result = dbcontext.PUB_PAGE_MANUSTRUCTURE.Where(w => w.PARENTID == null).ToList();
```

Comment: DataHelper.DataObj.QueryTable<PUB_PAGE_MENUSTRUCTUR>(SystemType.H0, p=>p.PARENTID == null);  i use the company platform,doesn't work

Comment: what does that mean??

Comment: our company have it's own dbcontext .

Comment: i think the problem is the == null . is there any way to replace that!

Comment: please specify what exact problem you are facing in your question

Comment: DataHelper.DataObj.QueryTable<PUB_PAGE_MENUSTRUCTUR>(SystemType.H0, p=>p.PARENTID == null); this lambda expression doesn't result in any data . i think it's as same as the " where PARENTID = null " show in the picture.

Comment: what i want to know is there any lambda expression represent for " where PARENTID is null" in the picture

Answer (score 0):

the answer is 
var result = dbcontext.PUB_PAGE_MANUSTRUCTURE.Where(w => w.PARENTID.Trim() == null).ToList();